# Fundamental operations of mathematics

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

I have read that addition, subtraction, multiplication, exponentiation and division are considered the fundamental operations in math.

Has this notion been made precise? Ie. is an operation considered fundamental if it cannot be defined in terms of other fundamental operations?

Can we know these are all the fundamental operations?

Is it possible to define complex conjugation in terms of the other five operations?

Comment: These are usually considered the four fundamental operations of *arithmetic*.  I don't think I would describe them as the fundamental operations of *mathematics*.

Comment: Well, can there be more operations which are not expressible in terms of the others, or are these 4 the only?

Comment: There are an enormous number of different operations used in mathematics, acting on many different sets of objects.  You mention complex conjugation, but there are also things like square root, logarithms, absolute value, composition of functions, matrix transpose, vector norm, matrix determinant, dot product, cross product, and so forth.  Some of these can be described in terms of the four basic  arithmetic operations, and some of them can't.

Comment: $x - y = x + ((-1)\times y)$ or $x/y = x \times y^{-1}$ show that subtraction and division are not *fundamental* in the sense of not being defined in terms of the others.

Comment: and $x+y=x-(0-y)$...

Comment: @JimBelk Are there fundamental operations of mathematics?

Comment: Not sure the answers given here are correct.

Answer (score 9):

In general, what is fundamental depends on what one chooses as foundations. Your question, in that sense, has no answer.

As for conjugation: there is no expression of a complex number $z$ involving only scalars and the five operations you listed which equals $\overline z$. A speedy argument is that any such expression denotes a function analytic on an open set of the complex plane, and $\overline z$ does not have that property; this has the disadvantage of requiring a bit of mathematical technology which maybe you don't have available :( Hopefully someone can come up with a simpler argument.

Answer (score 2):

These are important operations on structures in which they are defined, however to say they are fundamental operations in math isn't a very precise statement. In fact, using your definition, one can derive subtraction and division from addition and multiplication respectively. Abstract algebra provides a framework for studying various algebraic operations, but no operations are given precedence over the others.

Answer (score 0):

There are so to say six fundamental operations in arithmetics. Thase are 
1 Addition 2 Subtraction 3 Multiplication 4 Division 5 Inclusion (Exponentiation ie . Raising powers )
6 Exclusion ( Taking roots and radicals)
However there are,in a way, three pairs of arithmetical operations and in each pair an operation is reversal of its co-operation within the pair.Like addition and subtraction are reverse process of each other. Similar is the case for other operations as well.
With regard to Algebra one must understand that it is basically a set of rules based on these fundamental operations to make faster calculations and easy approach of problem solving using variables. With each Mathematical subject,is associated its own Algebra to analyse and draw infrences.Thus we have Algebra of Vectors,Algebra of Matrices,Algebra of Functions,Algebra of Sets,etc...It is worth noting that the concept of Zeros differ in many such subjects .